# Python: cronjob does not delete log files

Tags: python-3.x, cron

This is the sample code form my script.

```
import os, sys
import os.path
from datetime import datetime

# log rotation if above 1MB
def logCheck():
    if os.path.getsize('data.log') > 100000:
        print(f'Performing log rotation')
        os.remove('data_old.log') if os.path.exists('data_old.log') else None
        os.rename('data.log', 'data_old.log')
        sys.exit(0)


print(f'********** New execution starts **********')
now = datetime.now()
if now.strftime("%A") == 'Sunday' and now.strftime("%H") == '16':
    logCheck()

print(f'Script execution starts')
***other code***
```

When I run this script directly from command prompt `pyhton3 script.py`on sunday between 4 to 5 PM, it works perfectly. But when I run same using cronjob (on sundays), It does not rotate log.

```
00 16 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /absolute_path/script.py
```

It prints only `********** New execution starts **********` which means it enters if block inside logCheck function and exits without printing `Script execution starts` but somehow it does not rotate logs even my data.log file size is more than 1.5 MB.

Am I missing anything here?
I tried to provide all script related details here. Please let me know if you need further details. I am running this script on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server.

Comment: It probably fails at `if now.strftime("%A") == 'Sunday' and now.strftime("%H") == '16':` - Maybe there is a timezone discrepancy betwen the cronjob definition and the script. You could find out by printing `now`.

Comment: Timezones are matching. Also cronjob doesn't print 'Script execution starts' which means it enters IF condition inside logCheck function and exit using sys.exit . It somehow does not delete/rename log files.

Comment: It does not enter the if condition, as it does not print `Performing log rotation`. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach ohh, that was a foolish miss from my end. Now I got my answer. While removing and renaming files, I did not use absolute paths of files. That is why it does not work with crontab. Thanks.